# How to use datetimepicker in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm using redux form in my react application. I want to use datetimepicker, but the value is not going as null.

This is my code.

```
<Field name="year" value={this.state.year} component={(props) => {
    return (
       <DateTimePicker defaultValue={this.state.year} onChange={change.bind(this.state.year)} time={false} initialView={"decade"} format={"YYYY"}/>
    )
}}/>


let change = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        year: value
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here but you're not using `redux-form` at all. The whole point of using `redux-form` is to let it handle the state, whereas you're handling the state yourself. You shouldn't use `this.state` and you shouldn't pass a `value` to `Field` at all.

Because this question is too vague, I'll give you the path instead of an actual answer.

This is what you should do:

1. Forget about your `DateTimePicker` at first and make sure you can create a simple form. [Follow this tutorial](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/GettingStarted.md/) and in the end, make sure, through the Redux dev tools that your store contains a property called `contact` with all the information of the form inside.
2. Now, [follow this tutorial](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/#usage) to understand how to create a custom component. It will help you creating a `MyCustomInput`. Again, make sure the state of `MyCustomInput` is in the Redux state.
3. Now back to your `DateTimePicker`, check whether or not it is compliant with the `Redux-Form` `Field` interface. If it is, you can pass it like this: 
    `<Field name="date" component={DateTimePicker} type="text"/>`, otherwise, you'll have to wrap it in your own component.

Comment: Still data is not going.